# Leading Zero Issue when exporting excel from grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

In the below code i am export excel from grid when export the leading zeros get deleted.I want to maintain the leading zero.Please help me to solve the issue.

```
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Supply/DemandReport.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gdSupplyorDemand.AllowPaging = false;
gdSupplyorDemand.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

form.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
form.Controls.Add(gdSupplyorDemand);
this.Controls.Add(form);
form.RenderControl(hw);

string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-form at:\@;}</style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

In excel Number cell always strips the leading zeroes.One trick is to make it string instead of number.you can make use of `"\t"`.

For eg:-

```
     int Value=00123  
     string newValue="\t"+value;
```

This should work...

Comment: It should be placed here ? Response.Output.Write("\t"+sw.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

like @kyle said, add \t. but first declare a string and set value of string as sw.ToString(). That will solve your problem. Good Luck.